# How do I access a view using a table controller in Azure Mobile Apps?

Tags: sql-server, node.js, azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I would like to point my table at a view using a table controller in Azure Mobile Apps however despite my best efforts I cannot get any data to return, there is simply an `internal 500 server error`.  I followed some documentation : https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/15/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-8-table-controller-basics/ but it's as if my view cannot be reached.

Here is my table controller:

**mytable.js**

From my understand what we are saying here is that the table name is called `mytable` but I want it to look for a table called 'my_awesome_view' which is in fact a view not a table but as far as the mobile app is concered it should be fine.  Then we have some additional info like only returning 1000 items per page.

```
var table = require('azure-mobile-apps').table();

table.name = 'mytable';
table.schema = 'dbo';
table.dynamicSchema = true;
table.databaseTableName = 'my_awesome_view';
table.maxTop = 1000;

module.exports = table;
```

This code is stored on my azure server in `wwwroot/tables/mytable.js`

**MyDatabase/Views/dbo.my_awesome_view**

My view which is called `my_awesome_view` pulls back only a couple of columns under a single condition.  I've been told to include the additional columns that are created by Easy Tables in my view which are `deleted`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`

```
SELECT  mytable.id,
        name,
        deleted,
        createdAt,
        updatedAt
FROM    mytable 
WHERE   name = 'Bob'
```

I use an application called Postman for testing apis' and when I query this endpoint `https://mybackend.azurewebsites.net/tables/mytable` I get nothing back except this internal 500 server error.  The error message has no further details as to what's gone wrong.

Can anyone assist with this problem?  If I remove the code the table end point works fine, I get the feeling it's not reaching my view which is there.

**Update**

After some advice given by @AdrianHall I have looked at the log files for the application and also switched off the dynamic scheme option.  The application logs show the following error message:

`Error occurred during table initialization RequestError: Cannot alter 'dbo.my_awesome_view' because it is not a table.`

That makes sense because it's a view however it was my understanding that adding the code I have should allow the system to read my view.

Comment: 1) Turn dynamicSchema off - it doesn't work on views - only tables.  2) Turn on diagnostic logging in App Service and use the log viewer to see why the server is crashing.  I think dynamic schema is producing a schema view SQL command which is failing on the view.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information @AdrianHall I switched off `table.dynamicSchema` but it's not helped.  I checked the error logs, specifically the application logs and the error I find is the following.
`Error occurred during table initialization RequestError: Cannot alter 'dbo.my_awesome_view' because it is not a table.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working.  I can now access my view without any problems.  The issue was that when I created by view I didn't added a `version` column.  The documentation I've seen says you need to ensure all the columns are added not just one or two.  I simply missed version, once I added it the view started working and the conditional results are being returned.

So to ensure that everyone knows what I did here is my full source code:

**Step 1**
Create your view in your Azure database, in my case I used the SQL Management Studio on my local machine connected to my Azure database.  When you create your view add the following columns:

- `[version]`
- `[updatedAt]`
- `[createdAt]`
- `[deleted]`

Here is the full code I wrote to create my view.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[my_awesome_view]
AS
SELECT  id, 
        column_name_1,
        column_name_2,
        column_name_3,      
        [version],  
        updatedAt,
        createdAt,
        deleted 

FROM    mytable 
WHERE   (column_1 = 'Bob' OR
         column_2 = 'Smith' OR
         column_3 = 'Jr')

GO
```

**Step 2**

Create your class in your app.  If like me you are creating a Xamarin Forms hybrid app then you need to define your table class in the shared project.  The table class should reference the table name where the data comes from NOT the view name but it should still include the columns the view calls.

In my case my view selects data from `mytable` so my class name is `mytable.cs` respectively:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class mytable
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string column_1 { get; set; }
        public string column_2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Step 3**

Now that we have the basics in place we need to tell our app to look at the view but treat it like a table.  In my Azure portal I created a table API using Easy Tables in my Azure Mobile App, I specified `mytable` as the table to create the api for, Azure then creates the corrosponding javascript and json files for me.

Clicking on the table api you just created and selecting `Edit Script` will take you straight into the `wwwroot` where the javascript file is stored.  From here we change the table initilisation code to the following:

```
var table = require('azure-mobile-apps').table();
table.databaseTableName = 'my_awesome_view';       
module.exports = table;
```

You can do quite a lot in here with this file and Adrian Hall has an a good dive into what it can do as well as a table controller feature list which can be found here: https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/15/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-8-table-controller-basics/

I also set the permission of my api to read only by changing the `insert`, `update` and `delete` to `disabled` but leaving `Read` as `Allow anonymous`

That's it! Using an application like Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/) you can directly query your API and get your results back.

If you are having problem then be sure you switch on error logging so you can find out where the problem is.